# How to difference in an if clause between an input value or td text content in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Hello and thank you for take your time reading my issue.

I'm trying to set values to a matrix in the loop below:

```
for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
    for(var j=0;j<9;j++){
        var aux = i.toString().concat(j.toString());
        // If that I want
        var num = document.getElementById(aux).innerText;
        matriz[i][j] = num;
        // else
        var num = document.getElementById(aux).value;
        matriz[i][j] = num;

    }
}
```

I have this table in HTML (I'm not going to copy all the table):

```
<table id="tablero">
  <tr>
    <td> <input id="00" type="text" maxlength="1">  </td>
    <td id="01"></td>
    <td id="02"></td>
    <td id="03"></td>
    <td id="04"></td>
    <td> <input id="05" type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
    <td> <input id="06" type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
    <td id="07"></td>
    <td> <input id="08" type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="10"></td>
    <td> <input id="11" type="text" maxlength="1"> </td>
    <td> <input id="12" type="text" maxlength="1"> </td>
..
```

The td's without inputs have default values.
So, how can I differentiate them in the previous loop? Thanks in advance

Comment: Note: for consistency reasons, it could be better to keep all your ids in your `td` elements, and check if there is an input inside them in the loop. You might get into difficulties later with such structure

Comment: Yeah you're so right. For now I will try to solve several problems that I have and before the next step of my proyect I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check element is `HTMLInputElement` using `instanceof`

```
var el = document.getElementById(aux);
matriz[i][j] = el instanceof HTMLInputElement ? el.value : el.innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
    for(var j=0;j<9;j++){
        var aux = i.toString().concat(j.toString());
        if(document.getElementById(aux).tagName=="TD"){
        var num = document.getElementById(aux).innerText;
        matriz[i][j] = num;
        }else{
        var num = document.getElementById(aux).value;
        matriz[i][j] = num;
}
    }
}
```